# Тестирование приложения

Tags: android

Есть смартфоны А, B, C, D.
На смартфонах A B C приложение было протестировано успешно, а вот на смартфоне D приложение вылетает. Возможности протестировать на смартфоне D нет. Как узнать где вылетает программа? Или какие существую средства для тестирования андроид приложений?

Comment: "Возможности протестировать на смартфоне D нет." Совсем? Либо нет возможности лично протестировать?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja , и лично и совсем, допустим приложение у пользователя, который говорит, что приложение вылетает на определенном модуле программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте билд без обфускации, залейте на Google Play как open/closed beta, пошлите пользователю линк, пусть поставит и запостит вам крэш-репорт. Из него и узнаете где вылетает.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en